# How to make a blur (tilt shift like) effect in android?

Tags: android, camera

I'm trying to do blur(tilt shift like) effect to make pictures look like [this](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b2/Oregon_State_Beavers_Tilt-Shift_Miniature_Greg_Keene.jpg), which I guess adding blur to the top and the bottom of the image.

I wonder if I could do this effect in real-time when the user is looking at my camera view or worst case senario on a bitmap after taking the picture.

Comment: Note: A real tilt shift is not a post processing effect, it's a camera lens that lets you tilt and shift the fron lens elements, giving you a focal plane that is not parallel to the film plane.

Answer (score 0):

If you know how to do a basic blur, the effect you're looking for shouldn't be hard. Basically, you increase the blur strength the closer you are to the top/bottom edges of the image. Increasing the contrast/saturation is also common for 'tilt-shift' effects.

For ideas on how to do a fast blur in the first place, check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/98359/752320).

As for speed, I'm sure you could do this real-time, as log as you're only doing it on a preview-sized bitmap since those are really small, comparatively. Run the function again on the actual size image once it's taken.