# Some operations (Convolve, AffineTransform) on BufferedImage with 16 bit per channel result in garbled data

Tags: java, bufferedimage

Some operations on BufferedImages with 16 bit per channel result in images with random colored pixels. Is it possible to avoid this problem?

I see the problem at least with

- ConvolveOp
- AffineTransformOp with INTERPOLATION_BICUBIC on images with alpha channel

Sample code:

```java
Kernel kernel = new Kernel(2, 2, new float[] { 0.25f, 0.25f, 0.25f, 0.25f });
ConvolveOp blurOp = new ConvolveOp(kernel, ConvolveOp.EDGE_NO_OP, null);
img = blurOp.filter(img, null);
```

Input: [image: sample image] output image: [image: sample with random colored pixels]

The operations work fine when the image is 8 bit per channel.

I tried to convert the image from 16 to 8 bit per channel while keeping the color profile using the following code but this also results in a garbled image.

```java
private static BufferedImage changeTo8BitDepth(BufferedImage bi) {
    ColorModel cm = bi.getColorModel();
    boolean hasAlpha = cm.hasAlpha();
    boolean isAlphaPre = cm.isAlphaPremultiplied();
    int transferType = DataBuffer.TYPE_BYTE;
    int transparency = cm.getTransparency();
    ColorSpace cs = cm.getColorSpace();
    ColorModel newCm = new ComponentColorModel(cs, hasAlpha, isAlphaPre, transparency, transferType);
    WritableRaster newRaster = newCm.createCompatibleWritableRaster(bi.getWidth(), bi.getHeight());
    BufferedImage newBi = new BufferedImage(newCm, newRaster, isAlphaPre, null);
    // convert using setData
    newBi.setData(bi.getRaster());
    return newBi;
}
```

(It is possible to use ColorConvertOp to convert to an 8-bit sRGB image but I need the non-sRGB color profile.)

I tested on Java 8, 11, and 17 on macOS and Linux. For full source code and images for tests see https://github.com/robcast/java-imaging-test (class Test16BitColor)

Comment: @gpasch `BufferedImage` does indeed allow 16 bits per channel. 8 bits per channel is fine for computer display, but sometimes higher precision is required. Working with this higher precision involves more  number crunching. But it's definitively *not* magic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After som testing and research, I think the fact that `ConvolveOp` and `AffineTransformOp` doesn't work with 16 bits/sample (`TYPE_USHORT` data type) images out of the box, is a JDK bug. It might be that the underlying native code only works with 8 bits/sample images, but in that case "Op"s should throw an exception (or perhaps add a slower, but correct Java fallback code path). You might want to report that to the OpenJDK community.

---

For the 16 to 8 bits/sample conversion, the problem is you can't set 16 bit values into an 8 bit buffer, as there's no normalization done on the samples. I guess you'll just end up with the lower 8 bits of the 16 bits sample, which will typically look like static/noise. This can be fixed, however.

Here's a version that will convert the values correctly to 8 bit, but otherwise keep the color space/color profile unchanged:

```java
private static BufferedImage changeTo8BitDepth(BufferedImage original) {
    ColorModel cm = original.getColorModel();

    // Create 8 bit color model
    ColorModel newCM = new ComponentColorModel(cm.getColorSpace(), cm.hasAlpha(), cm.isAlphaPremultiplied(), cm.getTransparency(), DataBuffer.TYPE_BYTE);
    WritableRaster newRaster = newCM.createCompatibleWritableRaster(original.getWidth(), original.getHeight());
    BufferedImage newImage = new BufferedImage(newCM, newRaster, newCM.isAlphaPremultiplied(), null);

    // convert using createGraphics/dawImage
    Graphics2D graphics = newImage.createGraphics();
    try {
        graphics.drawImage(original, 0, 0, null);
    }
    finally {
        graphics.dispose();
    }

    return newImage;
}
```

If you prefer conversion using rasters only, it's also possible with some hacks:

```java
private static BufferedImage changeTo8BitDepth(BufferedImage original) {
    ColorModel cm = original.getColorModel();

    // Create 8 bit color model
    ColorModel newCM = new ComponentColorModel(cm.getColorSpace(), cm.hasAlpha(), cm.isAlphaPremultiplied(), cm.getTransparency(), DataBuffer.TYPE_BYTE);
    WritableRaster newRaster = newCM.createCompatibleWritableRaster(original.getWidth(), original.getHeight());
    BufferedImage newImage = new BufferedImage(newCM, newRaster, newCM.isAlphaPremultiplied(), null);

    // convert using setData
    // newImage.setData(as8BitRaster(original.getRaster())); // Works
    newRaster.setDataElements(0, 0, as8BitRaster(original.getRaster())); // Faster, requires less conversion

    return newImage;
}

private static Raster as8BitRaster(WritableRaster raster) {
    // Assumption: Raster is TYPE_USHORT (16 bit) and has PixelInterleavedSampleModel
    PixelInterleavedSampleModel sampleModel = (PixelInterleavedSampleModel) raster.getSampleModel();

    // We'll create a custom data buffer, that delegates to the original 16 bit buffer
    final DataBuffer buffer = raster.getDataBuffer();

    return Raster.createInterleavedRaster(new DataBuffer(DataBuffer.TYPE_BYTE, buffer.getSize()) {
        @Override public int getElem(int bank, int i) {
            return buffer.getElem(bank, i) >>> 8; // We only need the upper 8 bits of the 16 bit sample
        }

        @Override public void setElem(int bank, int i, int val) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Raster is read only!");
        }
    }, raster.getWidth(), raster.getHeight(), sampleModel.getScanlineStride(), sampleModel.getPixelStride(), sampleModel.getBandOffsets(), new Point());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort @harald-k! I tried the first `changeTo8BitDepth` using `drawImage()` and it does produce a mostly correct 8-bit image but it converts the colors in a non-sRGB color space incorrectly. sRGB red in a DCI-P3 color space which should be (241,0,0) becomes (234,51,35) while DCI-P3 red which should be (255,0,0) also becomes (234,51,35).

Comment: The `Raster` conversion method works and it produces the correct colors in a DCI-P3 color space ((241,0,0) for sRGB red and (255,0,0) for DCI-P3 red). Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with blurring a 16 bit `BufferedImage` and `ConvolveOp`, but in my case a grayscale picture (`BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY`). The image I needed to process is a heightmap.

I used the following code:

```
private static BufferedImage blur(BufferedImage img) {
    float[] matrix3 = {
            1f/9, 1f/9, 1f/9,
            1f/9, 1f/9, 1f/9,
            1f/9, 1f/9, 1f/9,
        };
    Kernel kernel = new Kernel(3, 3, matrix3);

    BufferedImageOp op = new ConvolveOp(kernel);
    return op.filter(img, null);
}
```

This results in the following artifacts (images cropped due to their large size):

Original image:

[image: original image]

Blurred image:

[image: imageblurred with ConvolveOp]

Now, instead of using `ConvolveOp`, I can achieve the same effect with blurring all rows and all cols individually in only one dimension (cf. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/98818)) with a factor of 1/3 instead of 1/9 in the matrix, because 1/3 * 1/3 = 1/9. The following code does this, but leads to the same artifacts as the `ConvolveOp` used above:

```
private static BufferedImage blur(BufferedImage img) {
    for (int x=0; x<img.getWidth(); x++) {
        for (int y=0; y<img.getHeight(); y++) {
            int y0 = Math.max(y-1, 0);
            int y1 = y;
            int y2 = Math.min(y+2, img.getHeight()-1);

            short s0 = ((short[]) img.getRaster().getDataElements(x, y0, null))[0];
            short s1 = ((short[]) img.getRaster().getDataElements(x, y1, null))[0];
            short s2 = ((short[]) img.getRaster().getDataElements(x, y2, null))[0];
            
            short sNew = (short) ((s0 + s1 + s2) / 3);

            img.getRaster().setDataElements(x, y, new short[] {(short)sNew});
        }
    }
    
    for (int x=0; x<img.getWidth(); x++) {
        for (int y=0; y<img.getHeight(); y++) {
            int x0 = Math.max(x-1, 0);
            int x1 = x;
            int x2 = Math.min(x+2, img.getWidth()-1);

            short s0 = ((short[]) img.getRaster().getDataElements(x0, y, null))[0];
            short s1 = ((short[]) img.getRaster().getDataElements(x1, y, null))[0];
            short s2 = ((short[]) img.getRaster().getDataElements(x2, y, null))[0];
            
            short sNew = (short) ((s0 + s1 + s2) / 3);

            img.getRaster().setDataElements(x, y, new short[] {(short)sNew});
        }
    }
    return img;
}
```

**Workaround**:

With the following code (added lines marked), I can get rid of these artifacts and the blurring is correct:

```
private static BufferedImage blur(BufferedImage img) {
    for (int x=0; x<img.getWidth(); x++) {
        for (int y=0; y<img.getHeight(); y++) {
            int y0 = Math.max(y-1, 0);
            int y1 = y;
            int y2 = Math.min(y+2, img.getHeight()-1);

            short s0 = ((short[]) img.getRaster().getDataElements(x, y0, null))[0];
            short s1 = ((short[]) img.getRaster().getDataElements(x, y1, null))[0];
            short s2 = ((short[]) img.getRaster().getDataElements(x, y2, null))[0];

            s0 += 32768; // ADDED LINE
            s1 += 32768; // ADDED LINE
            s2 += 32768; // ADDED LINE
            
            short sNew = (short) ((s0 + s1 + s2) / 3);
            sNew -= 32768; // ADDED LINE

            img.getRaster().setDataElements(x, y, new short[] {(short)sNew});
        }
    }
    
    for (int x=0; x<img.getWidth(); x++) {
        for (int y=0; y<img.getHeight(); y++) {
            int x0 = Math.max(x-1, 0);
            int x1 = x;
            int x2 = Math.min(x+2, img.getWidth()-1);

            short s0 = ((short[]) img.getRaster().getDataElements(x0, y, null))[0];
            short s1 = ((short[]) img.getRaster().getDataElements(x1, y, null))[0];
            short s2 = ((short[]) img.getRaster().getDataElements(x2, y, null))[0];

            s0 += 32768; // ADDED LINE
            s1 += 32768; // ADDED LINE
            s2 += 32768; // ADDED LINE
            
            short sNew = (short) ((s0 + s1 + s2) / 3);
            sNew -= 32768; // ADDED LINE

            img.getRaster().setDataElements(x, y, new short[] {(short)sNew});
        }
    }
    return img;
}
```

Final image:

[image: Imageblurred with workaround algorithm]

It seems to me like it has to do something with the Java `short` type being signed, while the type of the `BufferedImage` is unsigned, but I'm not yet completely sure about that. Maybe this helps solving your problem.

Comment: Interesting solution! I guess the artifacts I saw could also be due to numeric overflow/wrap of a short. Maybe that could help the JDK developers spot the problem in their code. I don't currently have the time to file a bug on the JDK.